# c#: Have class return value without direct variable reference

Tags: c#, return, return-value

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to create a class that returns a value by default without a method/variable reference.

```
public class Attribute
{
    public int defaultValue = _base + _mods;

    private int _base;
    private int _mods;

    public Attribute (int b, int m)
    {
        _base = b;
        _mods = m;
    }
}

public class UseAttribute
{
    private Attribute att;

    public Start()
    {
        att = new Attribute(5,2);
    }

    public void CheckAttribute()
    {
        console.WriteLine("att: " + att); //Outputs:"att: 7"
    }
}
```

Is this something that can be done, or would I have to always use att.defaultValue ?

Comment: There is no such things as a return value for a class. I think what you are actually looking for, if you want to "display an object" is to [override `ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method)

Comment: The string output was just an example.  My main use case for this is as an attribute for an rpg character that will almost always just need to return the combined base and modifiers value.  Sad to hear this isn't possible, but thank you for the quick reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way how to do this and it would be implicit or explicit conversion.

```
public class Attribute
{  
    private int _base;
    private int _mods;

    public Attribute (int b, int m)
    {
        _base = b;
        _mods = m;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(Attribute attr) => attr._base + attr._mods;

    public override string ToString() => $"{this._base + this._mods}";
}

public class UseAttribute
{
    private Attribute att;

    public UseAttribute()
    {
        att = new Attribute(5,2);
    }

    public void CheckAttribute()
    {
        console.WriteLine("att: " + att); //Outputs:"att: 7"
    }
}
```

In the end I would not go for it and better use method or property.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the implicit keyword.   Looks like I have some reading to do, thank you!